# Firebase Invite used with Facebook login

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-invites

Is there a way to use Firebase Invites SDK in iOS without using a Google Account?
Would like to use Facebook login or even better the Firebase Auth.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Comment: No as far as Im aware, then it is not possible right now

Comment: Any news on this? Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Facebook has unfortunately killed "Facebook Invites", so this is not possible.

Source: https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/16/facebook-kills-app-invites-the-native-app-like-button-and-other-dev-features/